# PolyAnalyst: Is there a list of Part of Speech Tags?

Tags: nlp, tagging, pos-tagger, part-of-speech

Can someone provide a list of the Pos Tagger tags assigned to the `_tagged` column that is created?  We need to know all the possible values that can be assigned and what each one means.  For example: `En_NN = noun`, `En_NNS = plural noun`, etc.

Similarly for `_chunked` columns (NP, VP, PP, etc.)

Similarly for `_low_chunked`/`_top_chunked` columns (Np, Vp, Jp, Rp, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

_parsed - result of the parser. Each token separated by spaces and sentences separated by empty line.

_tagged - result of postagging. After each token to be its tag through slash. Meaning of tags:

## **Common**

SPEC        |   any special symbols

PUNCT | any punctuation

## **Particle**

En_NEG | negator (not)

En_TO | infinitival to

En_AT | article (a an the)

En_OF | preposition (in at)

En_CC | conjunction coordinating (and or)

En_CS | conjunction subordinating (that as)

En_UH | interjection (oops)

## **Numeral**

En_CD | cardinal (one)

En_OD | ordinal (first)

## **Noun**

En_NN | singular nominative (cat)

En_NNS | plural nominative (cats)

En_NN$ | singular genitive (cat's)

En_NNS$ | plural genitive (cats')

## **Adjective**

En_JJ | positive (warm)

En_JJR | comparative (warmer)

En_JJT | superlative (warmest)

## **Adverb**

En_RB | positive (cheaply)

En_RBR | comparative (cheaper)

En_RBT | superlative (cheapest)

## **Verb**

En_MD | modal (may could)

En_VB | not third or plural (go)

En_VBZ | third singular (goes)

En_VBD | past tense (went)

En_VBN | past participle (gone)

En_VBG | present participle (going)

## **Pronoun**

En_PP | nominative (it he she you we)

En_PP$ | possessive (our its his their my your)

En_PPO | accusative (them it him me us you her thee)

En_PPL | reflexive (itself himself myself yourself)

_chunked, _low_chunked, _top_chunked - are different levels of chunker algorithm. ​top_chunked - the uppermost phrases, it is constructed as union of small rudimentary chunks.

The POS tagger chunker tags are:
Np - noun phrases
Vp - verb phrases
Jp - adjective phrases
Rp - adverb phrases
Pp - prepositional phrases
Sp - conjunctional phrases